# What is the best practice for formatting logs?

Tags: standards, logging

I'm writing a piece of honeypot software that will have extensive logging of interactions with it, I plan to log in plaintext `.log` files.

I have two questions, from someone who isn't too familiar with how servers log.

1. Firstly how shall I break up my log files, I'm assuming after running this for a month I don't want one big `.log` file, do I do this by day, month, year? Is there some standard for it?
2. The format of each line, do I have one standard delimiter that is whatever, *, -, +, anything? Is there a standard anywhere (my googling hasn't brought up much)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I like this format for log files:

```
$ python simple_logging_module.py
2005-03-19 15:10:26,618 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,620 - simple_example - INFO - info message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,695 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,697 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,773 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
```

This is from python's [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).
I usually have a file per day, one folder for each month, one folder for each year. You'll get huge log files that you can't edit properly otherwise.

```
logs/
  2009/
    January/
     01012009.log
     02012009.log
     ...
    February/
     ...
  2008/
   ...
```

Comment: With regards to doing this in Java, I'm looking at  java.util.logging.Logger, it logs in an XML format though, would it be preferable to stick to lines or leave the XML?

Comment: You should use log4j (http://logging.apache.org/) if you're using Java. It's a more flexible logging utility, there's a good tutorial here (http://www.laliluna.de/log4j-tutorial.html). If you need to parse/search the data XML may be preferable or you may even want to try mjv's suggestion to log to a database.

Comment: This is an old post, but it comes to the top when searching for best practices around logging. I found this resource that I think also adds to the discussion: https://reflectoring.io/logging-format/. Recommend the discussion around separators and also like the user's thoughts around content and structure for a log.

Comment: For what it's worth, 10 years on, I think structured logging is the way to go. e.g. http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/ or https://brandur.org/logfmt

Answer (score 26):

There is no standard for such a logging. And rolling, layout of files, it all depends on what you need. In general I have faced 3 main scenarios:

- **All in one file**. Seems not an option for you.
- **Fixed size rolling**. You define size when new log file is created once current file is bigger than defined value. Usually there is support out of a box for this in most `log4anything` packages.
- **Total custom rolling**. I've seen layouts like this

  - Every day gets it's own directory named in format of `YYYYMMDD`. If you don't stage your logs consider directory layout like YYYY\MM\YYYYMMDD as shown in other answers.
  - Inside this directory **fixed size rolling** should be used.
  - Every file has name `logfile_yyyymmdd_ccc.log` where `ccc` is increasing number. Adding time to file name is also a good idea (eg. to easily judge how many logs per minute you are generating)
  - To save space every log is compressed with zip automatically.
  - Last 3 days are allways kept uncompressed so you can have a quick access with `UNIX` text tools.

This custom one looked like this

```
logs/
  20090101/
     logfile_20090101_001.zip
     logfile_20090101_002.zip
     ...
  20090102/
     logfile_20090102_001.zip
     logfile_20090102_002.zip
   logfile_20090101_001.log
   logfile_20090101_002.log
   logfile_20090102_001.log
   logfile_20090102_002.log
```

There is also some bunch of good practices for good logging:

- **Always** keep date in your log file name
- **Always** add some name to your log file name. It will help you in the future to distinguish log files from different instances of your system.
- **Always** log time and date (preferably up to milliseconds resolution) for every log event.
- **Always** store your date as YYYYMMDD. Everywhere. In filename, inside of logfile. It greatly helps with sorting. Some separators are allowed (eg. 2009-11-29).
- In general avoid storing logs in database. In is another point of failure in your logging schema.
- If you have multithreaded system always log thread id.
- If you have multi process system always log process id.
- If you have many computers always log computer id.
- Make sure you can process logs later. Just try importing one log file into database or `Excel`. If it takes longer than 30 seconds it means your logging is wrong. This includes:

  - Choosing good internal format of logging. I prefer space delimeted since it works nice with `Unix` text tools and with `Excel`.
  - Choosing good format for date/time so you can easily import into some SQL databse or Excel for further proccesing.

Comment: It's true that there may be no standard, but things have advanced somewhat in the 14 years since this answer was provided.  People coming across this now may want to check out OpenTelemetry.  Not strictly speaking a standard, but does provide lots of solutions that you can use for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

To break up your log files, you could use an external application like [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) and let it take care of the dirty work.

As for the format of each line, there's no standard, so you should use what works best for you.  If you're going to automatically parse the log file later, then you might want to keep that in mind as you format the log output.

Comment: logrotate or a similar software is definitely the way to go. It keeps all the complexity of separating the log in multiple files in its own module (logrotate) so you can keep your app simpler. And logrotate is very configurable, so it will do it in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use a well-known logging library. Most logging libraries support rollover for you. Log4Net (.net) / Log4J (java) is a particularly good logging library to use, and it has a lot of options that you may find useful. Use whatever rollover interval works best for you. For a honeypot application, I think you will find hourly or daily turnover to work best. You could also use a fixed limit, like 256mb, to ensure that your log efforts don't overrun the available free disk space. Log4Net/Log4J supports this as well.

[Log4J @ Apache.Org](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html)
[Log4Net @ Apache.Org](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

The format of your logfiles should be setup according to your needs. It is highly desirable to use a delimiter that is unlikely to show up in your log input. For your application, this may not be possible. Under typical circumstances, some parties use spaces (NCSA logs), some parties use commas (to make CSV files), some parties use tabs (to make tab-delimited files). Each of these has their own benefits and drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Today (2022) we love **structured logging** and log **indexers** (like Elasticsearch or Loki). So we have to log in [NDJson](http://ndjson.org/) (new line delimetted Json).

Because log delivery agents have difficulty with log file rotation (who loves missing log events??) we avoid rotation (no more `logrotate`!!): instead we name files using date pattern or auto-incremented sequence and define policy to remove outdated files.

Don't work with individual files! Use **centralized log search engines**!!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format is in the past.

Comment: Totally agreed!

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion:

It being for a honeypot system (and unless the baddies are really whacking the application/site), you may **consider taking the extra time to log to a database instead**.

This will make the analysis and usage of the logs easier, and real-time  (i.e. you do not need to go through the ETL process prior to analyzing / browsing the logs.

This said being in a DB table(s) or in file(s), this doesn't preclude the need to **define a format**.  Tentatively, you can have a "*polymorphic*" format, with a few common attributes (ID, IP address, Timestamp, Cookie/ID, "level" [of importance/urgency]) followed by a short mnemonic code defining a particular event type (say "LIA" = login attempt, "GURL" = guessed url, "SQLI" SQL Injection attempt etc...) followed by a few numeric fields, and a few string fields which semantics will vary as per the mnemonic.  To summarize:

```
 - Id
 - TimeStamp  (maybe split in date and time)
 - IP_Address
 - UserID_of_sorts
 - // other generic/common fields that you may think of
 - EventCode   (LIA, GURL, SQLI...)
 - Message   Text message (varies with particular event instance)
 - Int1      // Numbers...
 - Int2
 - Str1      // ...and text which meaning varies with the EventCode
 - Str2
 - //... ?
```

Now... regardless of this going to a flat file or to SQL database (and maybe particularly if going to DB), you could/should **use a standard logging library**. Maybe **log4j** as suggested in other replies (although I'm not sure if it readily has bindings in Python, and anyway, the Python's standard logging module is +/- the same...) or even the [**Python's standard library's logging module**](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) can probably be tailored for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the most important is:

- Start records (lines) with date/time formatted after the [W3C’s profile of ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)
- Use tab as the field separator in records

Answer (score 1):

Log File

1. Make Log Entries Meaningful With Context
2. Use a Standard Date and Time Format
3. Use Local Time + Offset for Your Timestamps
4. Use Logging Levels Correctly
5. Split Your Logging to Different Targets Based on Their Granularity
6. Include the Stack Trace When Logging an Exception
7. Include the Name of the Thread When Logging From a Multi-Threaded Application